# LinkedList Insert Issue

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure

I was trying to code insert in linkedlist for position 0 (i.e. the beginning  of the linked list) and for other positions (like in between any two nodes and at the end of the linkedlist). The code is given below. But it seems to be not working as expected. Please let me know as to what I am doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void displayLL(Node *p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

Node *createLL(int A[], int n, Node *ll)
{
    Node *tmp, *last;
    ll = new Node;

    ll->data = A[0];
    ll->next = NULL;
    last = ll;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        tmp = new Node;
        tmp->data = A[i];
        tmp->next = NULL;
        last->next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
    return ll;
}

int countNodesLL(Node *p)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void InsertNodeLL(Node *p, int index, int value)
{
    Node *tmp;
    if (index < 0 || index > countNodesLL(p))
    {
        return;
    }
    tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = value;

    // This should insert in the beginning of the Linked List - but it is not working.
    if (index == 0)
    {
        tmp->next = p; // pointing next of tmp to p node
        p = tmp;       // making tmp as the HEAD of linkedList
    }
    // This inserts after 1st node, in between two nodes and at the end of the LL
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        tmp->next = p->next;
        p->next = tmp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    Node *linkedList = NULL;
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    linkedList = createLL(A, 8, linkedList);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    cout << endl;

    InsertNodeLL(linkedList, 0, 15);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    cout << endl;

    InsertNodeLL(linkedList, 4, 10);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the below output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 10 5 6 7 8
```

Expected Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
15 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
15 1 2 3 4 10 5 6 7 8
```

Please help me as to what is wrong in the code.

Comment: You are possibly updating `Node*` to point to the new head, but that pointer is only in the context of the called function. You can pass `Node**` or `Node*&` to update the the head node

Comment: Usage note: Try to make titles tell the reader something about what's in the question.  This helps answerers and future askers alike find your question. Right now they don't have much to work form. After all, if the LinkedList code was working as expected would you have asked this question?

Comment: `void InsertNodeLL(Node *p, int index, int value)` does not allow you to change the head pointer since `p` is passed by value. More accurately you change a copy that is passed to the function but the code that calls the function does not see the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes, first you didn't return a value back to the linked list since you passed the pointer by value, and second in your insert function you also do not return a value as well you are modifying the head variable so you lose the previous values. Also you want to insert at the 5th position not the 4th. When you make the changes inside the function you are only using local variables so after the stack frame gets popped your linked list doesn't get updated. You can use a global variable instead but if you are passing by value you have to return back to the caller if you wish to change the list in main. Here is my reimplementation of your code: `

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void displayLL(Node* p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

Node* createLL(int A[], int n, Node* ll)
{
    Node* tmp, * last;
    ll = new Node;

    ll->data = A[0];
    ll->next = NULL;
    last = ll;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        tmp = new Node;
        tmp->data = A[i];
        tmp->next = NULL;
        last->next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
    return ll;
}

int countNodesLL(Node* p)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return count;
}

Node* InsertNodeLL(Node* p, int index, int value)
{
    Node* tmp;
    Node* tmp2;
    if (index < 0 || index > countNodesLL(p))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = value;

    // This should insert in the beginning of the Linked List - but it is not working.
    if (index == 0)
    {
        tmp->next = p; // pointing next of tmp to p node
        p = tmp;
        return p;       // making tmp as the HEAD of linkedList
    }
    // This inserts after 1st node, in between two nodes and at the end of the LL
    else
    {
        tmp2 = p;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp->next = tmp2->next;
        tmp2->next = tmp;
        return p;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{

    Node* linkedList = NULL;
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    linkedList = createLL(A, 8, linkedList);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    cout << endl;

    linkedList = InsertNodeLL(linkedList, 0, 15);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    cout << endl;

    linkedList = InsertNodeLL(linkedList, 5, 10);
    displayLL(linkedList);
    return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: Not returning a value isn't necessarily a mistake per-se, but only the combination of that along with passing by value. I would argue the more sensible implementation is using a reference, since that would be closer to the intended operation in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: shouldn't we avoid reference as it might replace the existing code thereby preferring 'pass by value' and 'pass by address' over reference.

Comment: @Aveek What do you mean existing code? Passing a pointer is essentially the same as passing a reference (with minor caveats like refs can't be `null`). If you are referring to the fact that references can be muted then that is the same with passing a pointer i.e. address.

Comment: I was just stating some facts I learned about C++ reference in one C++ online course:
Pass by reference should be used for functions which has less number of lines to execute. It may become inline functions or pass by address (depends on compiler)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} *first = NULL;

void create(int A[], int n)
{
    int i;
    struct Node *t, *last;
    first = new Node;
    first->data = A[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        t = new Node;
        t->data = A[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}
void Display(struct Node *p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int count(Node *p)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void Insert(struct Node *p, int index, int x)
{
    struct Node *t;
    int i;
    if (index < 0 || index > count(p))
        return;
    t = new Node;
    t->data = x;
    // When a node needs to be inserted at the beginning
    if (index == 0)
    {
        t->next = first;
        first = t;
    }
    // When a node needs to be inserted in between two nodes or at the last
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            p = p->next;
        t->next = p->next;
        p->next = t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    create(A, 5);
    Insert(first, 0, 5);
    Display(first);
    cout << endl;
    Insert(first, 2, 15);
    Display(first);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This too works!!